# How can I be notified of a bluetooth connection when the iOS app is backgrounded in Xamarin?

Tags: ios, xamarin, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

We need our app to receive notifications from the OS when the connects or disconnects from a bluetooth audio device (specifically, the one in their car).

The app gets notified when the BT device initially connects, but it then immediately seems to disconnect and logs the error:

> BTCentralManager::DisconnectedPeripheral > SoundCore mini(ATT)
>   ERROR Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=7 **"The specified device has disconnected from us."**

...and the "DisconnectedPeripheral" event is never actually fired.

We're unsure how to simply receive connect and disconnect events while the app is backgrounded.

Do we need to connect the peripheral with the central manager? We only need to know if the audio device is connected or not - we don't need to interact with it in any way.

The events never call a second time from the background, after getting the disconnect peripheral.  Presumably because of the error message we are receiving.

Sample code below:

```
public class BTCentralManager : CBCentralManagerDelegate
{
    public CBCentralManager centralManager;
    public static CBPeripheral peripheral;

    public BTCentralManager()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("BTCentralManager::Constructor > ");

        centralManager = new CBCentralManager(this, new DispatchQueue("myqueue"),
            new CBCentralInitOptions { ShowPowerAlert = true, RestoreIdentifier = "myRestoreIdentifier" });

        NSUuid[] arr = { new NSUuid("7e9002be-547f-42bc-8d56-209736f70aa2") }; //Sound core mini          

        var devices = centralmanager.retrieveperipheralswithidentifiers(arr);
        peripheral = devices.firstordefault();

        //is the only way to trigger the events, we need to first connect the peripheral to central manager???
       centralManager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, new PeripheralConnectionOptions
       {
           NotifyOnConnection = true,
           NotifyOnDisconnection = true,
           NotifyOnNotification = true
       });

    }

    //Always is triggered inclusive in background
    public override void UpdatedState(CBCentralManager central)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("BTCentralManager::UpdatedState > " + central.State.ToString());
    }

    //Only is triggered when the device is first time connected  ( Inclusive in background)
    public override void ConnectedPeripheral(CBCentralManager central, CBPeripheral peripheral)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("BTCentralManager::ConnectedPeripheral > " + peripheral.Name);

        //After the connect made successfully I receive this error, and never connect again to the device
        //Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=7 "The specified device has disconnected from us."
    }

    public override void DisconnectedPeripheral(CBCentralManager central, CBPeripheral peripheral, NSError error)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("BTCentralManager::DisconnectedPeripheral > " + peripheral.Name + " ERROR>" + error.Description);
    }

    public override void DiscoveredPeripheral(CBCentralManager central, CBPeripheral peripheral, NSDictionary advertisementData, NSNumber RSSI)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("BTCentralManager::DiscoveredPeripheral > " + peripheral.Name);
        //   base.DiscoveredPeripheral(central, peripheral, advertisementData, RSSI);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand your question, you need to observe the availability of a bluetooth audio device. I had some investigations in this a couple of time ago and the result was not really satisfying me. Here's my conclusion:

1.) CoreBluetooth is intented to be used for Bluetooth 4.0 / Bluetooth Low Energy devices only. Many Bluetooth headphones or even car radios are still not bluetooth 4.x. So, unless you can rely on your user's bluetooth audio device to be 4.x, CoreBluetooth might be a waste of time.

2.) Your app wont be notified about a audio device being connected when your app is in background.

So far no good. But, there might be some approaches that may help.

1.) By using the CLLocationManager, you may start observing e.g. the compass (not the location to save battery) to get notified whenever the phone has been moved. Simply check the connected audio devices when the app is calling the CLLocationManagerDelegate. This is of course not very efficient, but it might work.

2.) use iBeacons and CLBeaconRegions if available. Place an iBeacon in the user's car and start observing the beacon.

I know, this is not exactly what you want to hear, but I'm afraid there's no straight forward solution for your problem.

cheers,
Peter